# Apache Httpd.conf Relative Paths

Tags: windows, apache, relative-path, httpd.conf

I'm trying to configure Apache to use relative paths in its httpd.conf file so that the server can be moved around without breaking anything.

I have changed ServerRoot to "../", but this causes some serious problems.

When I start Apache from the command line with `httpd.exe`, everything works fine, but if I try to install it and run it as a service, with `httpd.exe -k install` and `net start Apache2.4`, it gives a service-specific error code of 1 and will not start the service.

If I set ServerRoot to "./", the command `httpd.exe` will not work, (Apache cannot find its modules) but it can be installed and run as a service!

Is there a way to set Apache up with relative paths so that it can be run from the command line and as a service?

I am using Windows 7 Pro 64-bit and Apache 2.4.7 32-bit if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `./../` as server root. Setting current directory `./` and then going one step back `../` as httpd.exe is located in bin directory. Of course the modules directory needs to be in the same directory as the bin directory.